# USSD response is numeric

Tags: sms, at-command, ussd

```
AT+CUSD=1,"service_code",15

+CUSD: 0,"0056006F0074007200650020006300720065006400690074002000730074006F0072006D002D0063007200650064006900740020006500730074002000310036003500310032002E00300030002000440069006E00610072002E",72
```

How to get readable response? thanks.

this is AT&V:

&C: 1; &D: 2; &E: 0; &F: 0; &S: 0; &W: 0; E: 0; L: 0; M: 0; Q: 0; V: 1;X: 1; Z: 0; \Q: 3; \S: 0; \V: 0; S0: 0; S2: 43; S3: 13; S4: 10; S5: 8;S6: 2; S7: 60; S8: 2; S9: 6; S10: 14; S11: 95; S30: 0; S103: 1; S104: 1;+FCLASS: 0; +ICF: 3,3; +IFC: 2,2; +IPR: 115200; +DR: 0; +DS: 0,0,2048,6;+WS46: 12; +CBST: 0,0,1;+CRLP: (61,61,48,6,0),(61,61,48,6,1),(240,240,52,6,2);+CV120: 1,1,1,0,0,0; +CHSN: 0,0,0,0; +CSSN: 0,0; +CREG: 0; +CGREG: 0;+CFUN:; +CSCS: "IRA"; +CSTA: 129; +CR: 0; +CRC: 0; +CMEE: 2; +CGDCONT: (1,"IP","internet","0.0.0.0",0,0); +CGDSCONT: ; +CGTFT: ; +CGEQREQ: ; +CGEQMIN: ; +CGQREQ: ; +CGQMIN: ;+CGEREP: 0,0; +CGDATA: "PPP"; +CGCLASS: "A"; +CGSMS: 1; +CSMS: 0;+CMGF: 1; +CSAS: 0; +CRES: 0; +CSCA: "+21350001701",145; +CSMP: ,,0,0;+CSDH: 0; +CSCB: 0,"",""; +FDD: 0; +FAR: 0; +FCL: 0; +FIT: 0,0; +ES: ,,;+ESA: 0,,,,0,0,255,; +CMOD: 0; +CVHU: 1; +CPIN: ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ,ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ;+CMEC: 0,0,0; +CKPD: 1,1; +CIND: 0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0; +CMER: 0,0,0,0,0;+CGATT: 0; +CGACT: 0; +CPBS: "SM"; +CPMS: "ME","ME","ME";+CNMI: 3,1,0,2,0;  +CMMS: 0; +FTS: 0; +FRS: 0; +FTH: 3; +FRH: 3; +FTM: 96;+FRM: 96; +CCUG: 0,0,0; +COPS: 1,0,""; +CUSD: 1; +CAOC: 1; +CCWA: 1;+CCLK: ""; +CLVL: 2; +CMUT: 0; +CPOL: 0,2,"",0,0,0; +CPLS: 0; +CTZR: 0;+CTZU: 0; +CLIP: 1; +COLP: 0; +CDIP: 0; +CLIR: 0; +ZSNT: 0,0,0;+ZDLFREQ: 0,0; +ZOPRT: 0; +CMVL: 0

Comment: Thats pdu, issue AT+CMGF=1 to switch to text mode

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Basic answer is just interpret each 2 byte as string representation of hex number. Each 2 number is UCS-2 symbol.
So your string is

```
Votre credit storm-credit est 16512.00 Dinar.
```

Long answer is you need read `3GPP TS 23.038 V13.0.0 (2015-12)` and interpet `72` value to figure out how to decode this string.
In your case is `group=0100 coding=UCS2 compressed=false`.

Also I think `+CMGF` has no affect to `+CUSD`. It more for sms related command. You can try set `at+cscs="IRA"` to seitch your charset but I do not think it helps with UCS2 and this is not standart way.

**3GPP TS 27.007 V13.4.0 (2016-03)**

> if `dcs` indicates that 16-bit data coding scheme (UCS2) is used:
>   MT/TA splits the 16 bits into two 8-bit octets. Each of those octets
>   are converted as per the 8-bit data coding scheme, with the most
>   significant octet first (e.g. decimal value 4906 is presented to TE as
>   four characters 132A (IRA 49, 51, 50 and 65))

Byt my WaveCom SIM300 send UCS2 directly if set IRA and hex string if set HEX.